# Solr Search For MediumText field

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using solr successfully with asp.net however I have a new search I need to create based on a mediumtextfield in mysql. I need to search that entire field against the index.

Is there a best-practice approach for this? e.g. to select keywords from the mediumtext field first?

Thanks.

Comment: That would depend on what you want to achieve. Solr has a (configurable) restriction of 1024 terms per search. Going above this is likely to have a performance impact. Could you describe a bit more what you are doing?

Comment: The mediumtext field contains a ticket description from an employee. I want to find suggested solutions from our knowledgebase based on the ticket description. The title, article and tags of the knowledgebase are all indexed in solr under the same fieldname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're going to have to remove common words to get a decent hit rate. You could use the StopWords functionality and a list like http://www.lextek.com/manuals/onix/stopwords1.html

Once this done then matter of picking a search strategy that you think will work best based on test data?

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard

Good Luck :)